# Filter out the accelerometers noise using Kalman filter in Python

Tags: python, filter, accelerometer, kalman-filter

I get from a socket a stream of data from an accelerometer with a lot of noise.

```
something like this:
...
-0.014532123
0.183950298
0.003323536
-0.342343526
...
```

I tried with low pass filter but I can't get a really smoothed result..
I think I need to use Kalman filter so I have to implement
a function that "corrects" every element of the stream

```
stream_element_out = kalman(stream_element_in)
```

I'm using python and I searched all over the web, finding many examples, but I can't understand how I can apply it to my project :)..
someone can explain me an easy way to implement this algorithm please? :)

Comment: Normally the way these things work is that you supply an implementation and we tell you how to fix and or use it.

Answer (score 1):

Taking an average of the last `x` results could do the smoothing.

`x` would be a constant that can be tweaked for the best results depending on your application

You can also filter out input that is more than `y` off from the average of the last `x` numbers.